# IOS production certificate, whats should i provide to other parties to use the same cert?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

My current process is to revoking a production certificate which will be expired soon in the developer account.

I follow the step mentioned in the website :

https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File

to generate a new production certificate.

What i want to ask is that if i want to enable other parties to use the same certificate for signing production IOS application, what file should i send them in order to achieve this?

(the answer i searched so far is to generate a .p12 file for the certificate together with the .certSigningRequest which we uploaded to the apple developer website to generate a new certificate)

Why we should provide these file to other parties and how they use those file to generate same production certificate for signing?

Moreover, since in the apple developer website can directly download the .cert file for the production certificate, can other parties just download the .cert file (only the .cert file but not obtaining other files) and use it directly for code signing?

Thanks a lot, and sorry for long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want sharing production cer with your parties, you need provide them a .p12 file and a .mobileprovision, A .p12 file contain a private key which identified your team and a trust team member of this team.

To use this .p12 file just drag it to keychain or double click it then type the password for .p12 file.

The cer downloaded from developer center directly don't have a private key, it can't provide a trusted member let you to sign your app, so the answer to the last question is No.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And may i ask if the '.mobileprovision' file is the provisioning profile that we choose to associate with the production cert?

Comment: @ProgrammingBaKa Yes

Comment: And it seems that the Xcode will auto detect if the provisioning profile had changed in the apple developer website, do other parties can just directly download the new pp from Xcode if they have the .p12 certificate file?

Comment: If they can update the pp by themselves, i don't see the point why we should download the pp and send to them. btw really thanks for your help

Comment: @ProgrammingBaKa if Xcode signed in with the same Apple ID, they can just download the pp file from Xcode